# crontab entry for scheduling over night

Tags: linux, cron

I need to schedule a script every two minutes from 10 PM to 5 AM next day from Monday to Friday, but I'm not exactly sure if the below is correct and will work, or if there's other correct answers...

```
*/2 22-00 * * 1-5  /myscript.sh
*/2 00-05 * * 2-6  /myscript.sh
```

Update: I expect to start it from Sunday night at 10 PM and from then I expect it to run  22-05 every day till Friday.

Comment: When you say you want it to run from Mon-Fri, does that mean that you:  A> expect the script to start running at 0000 Monday morning, and stop being run at 0000 Saturday morning, or B> that you do _not_ want it to run from 0000-0458 on Monday but _do_ want it to run from 0000-0458 on Saturday?

Comment: @DopeGhoti: I expect to start it from Sun night 10 PM and from then i expect it to run in schedulation of `22-05` every day till Fri...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first entry specifies a range that runs backwards.  That should instead be

```
*/2 22-23 * * 1-5  /myscript.sh
```

This covers the range from 22:00 to 23:58, Monday through to Friday.

The second entry should probably not use zero-filled numbers:

```
*/2 0-4 * * 1-5 /myscript.sh
```

This covers the range 00:00 to 04:58.

The two schedules above would, together, run `/myscript.sh` every two minutes from 22:00 to 04:58 every Monday through to Friday (starting at 00:00 on Monday morning, ending at 23:58 on Friday evening).

These two could be combined into

```
*/2 22-23,0-4 * * 1-5 /myscript.sh
```

See also this schedule on the [crontab guru site](https://crontab.guru/#*/2_22-23,0-4_*_*_1-5).

Would you want a final run at exactly 5 AM, add an extra schedule:

```
0 5 * * 1-5 /myscript.sh
```

---

Taking your updated question into account into account:

```
*/2 22-23     * * 7   /myscript.sh
*/2 22-23,0-4 * * 1-4 /myscript.sh
*/2 0-4       * * 5   /myscript.sh
0   5         * * 1-5 /myscript.sh
```

This runs `/myscript.sh` every two minutes from 22:00 to 05:00, from Sunday at 22:00 through to Friday at 05:00.

1. The 1st schedule runs the Sunday evening jobs.
2. The 2nd schedule runs the the evening and morning jobs (until 04:58), Mondays to Thursdays.
3. The 3rd schedule runs the Friday morning jobs (until 04:58).
4. The 4th schedule runs the 05:00 jobs Mondays to Fridays.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer, i was of not aware that `22-23` actually means that my script will run from `22-23:58` every 2 mins...

Comment: @User123 See update at end in the light of your comment to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in one entry:

```
*/2 22-23,0-4 * * * /path/to/myscript.sh
```

This will execute `/path/to/myscript.sh` every two minutes from 22:00 to 04:58, every day.

Taking into account the clarifying addendum to the question, this cannot be done in one entry as there are different run-times on different days.  As such:

```
*/2 22-23 * * 0-5 /path/to/myscript.sh  # Execute from 2200-2358 Sun-Fri
*/2 00-04 * * 1-5 /path/to/myscript.sh  # Execute from 0000-0458 Mon-Fri
```